# SP Search - Error when copying a a Query Rule

Tags: search, query-rule

I ultimatly want to change the display template for the people result (showed horizontally right under the search textbox) in the "Everything"-search.

To do so Ive been instructed to go to the search site Collection->Settings->Query Rules, find "People name in SharePoint Search", copy that and then modify my copy.

When left-click and select "copy" I get the error message

> Sorry, something went wrong - Object with Id
>   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 already exists in the collection

This does not mean anything to me (except that I agree that something went wrong)

Ive testet it on three different Environments, with same result.

Anyone else got this problem? any solutions or leads?
(work-around would probably be to change the original display template on server)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, rather a work-around, instead of copying an existing Query Rule, I created a new one following [this guide](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.se/2013/03/sharepoint-2013-adding-people-to.html)